# How can I change the workflow's yml file in an Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I have created a Static Web App with GitHub in Azure. The app and the API work well, the URL is something like `https://[random-name].azurestaticapps.net`, and the source is the `main` branch in GitHub. My problem is that I want to change the name of GitHub's workflow file in the Static Web App configuration from `azure-static-web-apps-[random-name].yml` to `release-build.yml`. This is the file that is in the GitHub repo's directory: `.github/workflows/`.

To recap, I can rename the workflow file I have in GitHub from `azure-static-web-apps-[random-name].yml` to `release-build.yml`, but I can't do it in the Static Web App resource in Azure. Where can I rename that config in **Azure**? I've browsed in the docs and in the configurations but I don't know where to do it.

The pictures attached are my config in Azure and my config in GitHub. Any help is appreciated.

Azure:
[image: Azure's config]

GitHub:
[image: Github config]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been confirmed to be a known issue ([link](https://twitter.com/nthonyChu/status/1389671502988005376?s=20)), and might be fixed in later releases.

Currently there is no workaround so you have to keep using the default generated file name.

Comment: Thank you for referring to my tweet, as you can see on the thread I only posted this question because Azure support suggested it. I hope they can make a release for this feature soon.